# Show folders in document library that have a filter view

Tags: 2010, document-library, filter, folder, list-view

I am using SharePoint 2010

I have a document library with a view that Filter items only when a particular Column is true.

The problem now is that when I have a filter in my view the folders in my library do not show up.

What must I do in order for my view to show the folders as well?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or "Content Type" is equal to "Folder":

[image]

**NOTE FOR SHAREPOINT ONLINE:**

This filter won't work on *Sharepoint online*. Here's is the answer to filter by type folder :

[View only Folder items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283094/view-only-folder-items/283096#283096)

Answer (score 3):

The filter that worked for my library view... to show only "ABC" related folders and documents is shown below. Remember that SharePoint appears to be unix-based in that things are case-sensitive, so where "Folder" worked in the below filter, "folder" did not. Also note that, since most users who are creating folders don't apply categories, I used the "Name contains ABC" to get the appropriate folders to appear in my view.

Filter:

---

Content Type

is equal to

Folder

or

Content Type

is equal to

Document

and

Training Program

is equal to

ABC Training

or

Name

contains

ABC

---

Strangely enough, i had no luck at finding a list of content types, to enable me to have the library show documents as well as folders and vice versa. Again strangely, "Document" was *not* listed... but does indeed seem to be a type, as I successfully used it in my filter.

Below-listed are the default types in our MOSS installation. To see those, i had to goto to Library Settings, Advanced Settings, and checked Yes for "Allow Management of Content Types?". Then the Content Types section appeared above the Columns Section, and i was able to view our content types by clicking "Add from existing site content types." (I then went back in to revert our setting to not allow management of content types for that library.)

SharePoint 2010 Content Types

Article Page

Audio

Basic Page

Form

Image

Document

Link to a Document

List View Style

Master Page

Page

Page Layout

Picture

Project Page

Publishing Master Page

Redirect Page

Report

Report Builder Model

Report Builder Report

Report Data Source

Rich Media Asset

Summary Task

Video

Web Part Page

Web Part Page with Status List

Welcome Page

Answer (score 0):

Further down, your should see and option for folders. Is the show items with folders checked or is it set to show items without folders?