# View only Folder items

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter, view, modern-experience

Can someone explain to me why this is not working (and how to make it work)?:

[image: Filter only by folder]

Steps to reproduce :

- Go to a folder in all document view > edit current view > click show items only when the following is true:

  - `show the items when column`
  - Type
  - is equal to
  - Folder

Result: No items are being shown. zilch, zip, nada.

I have tried all variants of caps possible, space before and after. What is even more upsetting is this:

[image: Type is Folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such Type like "Folder" in document library. Type of Folder is always "Empty".

[image]

So to filter a view to only show the folders you need to use your filter like below (this is how I did it before):

[image]

**Notes**:

1. As we are adding filter to show the only items with "Empty" type, if you will upload any file without extension then it will be shown in the view.
2. View filters are at the document library level and not folder levels. So, all the files inside folder and sub-folders will be hidden in this particular view.

Comment: Thanks, just wasted a day of my life trying to figure this out. Unfortunately, this will also show files that have no file extension, but I guess that will work for now.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped you. And yes, it will show the files without extension as well. see the "Notes" in my answer.